# Java Bukkit delay with Schedule in another class

Tags: java, this, scheduler, bukkit

im trying to delay a command in a bukkit plugin. This is the acutal scheduler is used for it.

```
public class Particle implements CommandExecutor
{

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg) {

    if (sender instanceof Player)
    {
            Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                player.sendMessage("blabla");

            }

        }, 12);
return true;
}

return false;
}
```

This is how I implemented my Particle class into the plugin.

```
public void onEnable(){
    this.getCommand("part").setExecutor(new Particle());
}
```

Because this scheduler is inside a class and I need a reference to my plugin I cant use "this" at scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){
What do I use instead get a reference to my plugin?

Comment: Please give us a real [mcve]

Comment: Well what example should I give? I need a reference to my plugin when being inside a class. If I would be inside my main class of the plugin I could use this.. What do I use instead here.

Comment: Like the code around this method call? How are we supposed to know what class this is in and thus what this this is referring to?

Comment: I added the important parts of the class. So basicly I use a command and the server should answer a bit delayed.

Comment: I found what I was looking for, anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the reference to your JavaPlugin class as a constructor to your listener

```
private JavaPlugin plugin;


public Particle(JavaPlugin plugin){
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(/* Do your thing*/){
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, /*...*/);
}
```

And then, you set the listener as a new instance of Particle

```
setExecutor(new Particle(this), /*...*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem myself. For those that are looking for the same thing. You need to change

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){
```

to

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(JavaPlugin.getProvidingPlugin(<NameOfTheClassYouAreIn.class), new Runnable(){
```

Comment: This may work, but according to the Javadocs, you might face a IllegalStateException depending on where you're calling it in